# Is there a way in Visual Studio to see the actual objects in memory

Tags: c#, visual-studio, object, visual-studio-2015

I would like to see the objects created by my program. I searched on google and stack and I looked around in visual studio but I can't find anything about this.

I'm not looking for memory usage analyzer view. I just want to see all created objects and their values.

Is there a way to see all live objects in Visual Studio 2015?

Comment: What do you mean by in memory? Do you mean like the locals window? It lists all variables and their values. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa290840(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: I think what you are asking for does not exist. You can add variables you know exist to the watch window and that will show their values (if they are in scope). But you can't see "everything". What are your reasons behind wanting this?

Comment: Assuming you don't need it realtime, a memory profiler is the way to go.

Comment: @botenvouwer: I think currently the option to show all the objects is to use `sos` from `WinDbg`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can see the memory of the object by using `Memory` window in VS.

Just go to `Debug->Windows->Memory` and open one of the four available or use the shortcut `Ctrl+Alt+M, 1-4`. Then while debugging the application just type the name of the variable in the address field to translate it to a memory location and show the memory.

Assuming you code is like this:

```
var memObject = new MemObject {IntField = 42, StringField = "String"};
var str = "My string";
```

and you have a breakpoint after the second line. When you type `str` into and address field you will be moved to the memory location of this object

[image]

the same goes with writing `memObject` there.

If you want to see all the objects I think the only way is to us `sos` in WinDbg.

Comment: Thanks, you helped me find what I was looking for. In my case I was looking for Debug -> Windows -> Locals

Comment: happy that this was helpful.